# Insert values in session variable CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

how can i insert indexes into my session variable "ses_list" in CodeIgniter i know how to update the session variable values but how can more values be inserted into the variable keeping with previous values.

```
[ses_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Value 1
            )

    )
```

what i want is something like this

```
    [ses_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Value 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Value 1
            )

    )
```

i am stuck any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok.what problem you have got in inserting.?

Comment: how are you doing it? can you show us the code ?

Comment: i am making an array and storing it into a variable
$new is the variable name in which array is stored.
`$this->session->set_userdata( array('ses_user_player_list' => $new );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play it like normal array

```
  $this->session->set_userdata('ses_list', array('value1','value2'));
```

Next time when you want to add more data, get the same array from session, add values and again update in session

```
  $ses_list = $this->session->userdata('ses_list');
  $ses_list[] = 'value3';
  $ses_list[] = 'value4';
  $ses_list[] = 'value5';
  $this->session->set_userdata('ses_list', $ses_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all, are you saving the data in the session?

Remember you should load the library:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then for what you try to do: (**note the $array**)

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

You should read the [Session class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)